# Change field dynamically in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm developing a project, and when typing a value in one field, I need the other field to be changed based on the values ​​I defined in a function, here is the code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        yieldMonth: '',
        risk: '',

    }


}

changeYieldMonthHandler= (event) => {
    this.setState({yieldMonth: event.target.value});
}

changeRiskHandler= (event) => {
    this.setState({risk: event.target.value});
}
```

> In the function below, I check the amount that will be inserted in the
> Monthly Income field, which should impact the risk field:

```
definesRisk(){
    if (this.state.yieldMonth != null){
        if (this.state.yieldMonth > 6000){
            this.state.risk= "A";
        } else if (this.state.yieldMonth > 1000 && this.state.yieldMonth <= 8000){
            this.state.risk = "B";
        } else {
            this.state.risk = "C";
        }
    }
}
```

> And here is my render, where it should be updated dynamically
> according to the value of the field Monthly income. I'm trying to do
> it that way, does anyone help me know where I'm going wrong?

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>

                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label> Yield Month: </label>
                                    <input type ="Number" placeholder="Yield Month:" name="yieldMonth" className="form-control"
                                    value={this.state.yieldMonth} onChange={this.changeYieldMonthHandler} onBlur={this.definesRisk} />
                                </div>

                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label> Risk: </label>
                                    <input disabled type ="Number" placeholder="" name="risk" className="form-control"
                                           value={this.state.risk} onChange={this.definesRisk()} />
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: You are mutating the state directly `this.state.risk= "A";`. You should always use setState to change the state. `this.setState({risk: 'A'})`

Comment: @RinkeshGolwala 
thank you so much man, problem fixed!

Answer (score 2):

There is a big problem here:

The way that you're updating the `state.this.state.risk='A'` is not the correct way, instead you should call the setState method like this `this.setState({risk:'A'})`

```
definesRisk(){
    if (this.state.yieldMonth){
        if (this.state.yieldMonth > 6000){
            this.setState({risk:'A'});
        } else if (this.state.yieldMonth > 1000 && this.state.yieldMonth <= 8000){
           this.setState({risk:'B'});
        } else {
           this.setState({risk:'C'});
        }
    }
}
```

Also you had a `closing form tag` without an `opening form tag`.

Your code using class based components:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default class extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      yieldMonth: "",
      risk: ""
    };
  }

  changeYieldMonthHandler = (event) => {
    this.setState({ yieldMonth: event.target.value });
  };

  definesRisk() {
    if (this.state.yieldMonth > 6000) {
      this.setState({ risk: "A" });
    } else if (this.state.yieldMonth > 1000 && this.state.yieldMonth <= 8000) {
      this.setState({ risk: "B" });
    } else {
      this.setState({ risk: "B" });
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    if (prevState.yieldMonth !== this.state.yieldMonth) {
      this.definesRisk();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label> Yield Month: </label>
            <input
              type="Number"
              placeholder="Yield Month:"
              name="yieldMonth"
              className="form-control"
              value={this.state.yieldMonth}
              onChange={this.changeYieldMonthHandler}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label> Risk: </label>
            <input
              disabled
              type="text"
              placeholder=""
              name="risk"
              className="form-control"
              value={this.state.risk}
            />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Notice that in order to call your `definesRisk`  methode whenever the state updates i've used `componentDidUpate lifecycle method`

Here is your your code using react functionnal components with hooks :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [yieldMonth, setYieldMonth] = useState("");
  const [risk, setRisk] = useState("jkkkj");

  const changeYieldMonthHandler = (event) => {
    setYieldMonth(event.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const definesRisk = () => {
      if (yieldMonth > 6000) {
        setRisk("A");
      } else if (yieldMonth > 1000 && yieldMonth <= 8000) {
        setRisk("B");
      } else {
        setRisk("C");
      }
    };
    definesRisk();
  }, [yieldMonth]);

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label> Yield Month: </label>
          <input
            type="Number"
            placeholder="Yield Month:"
            name="yieldMonth"
            className="form-control"
            value={yieldMonth}
            onChange={changeYieldMonthHandler}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
          <label> Risk: </label>
          <input
            disabled
            type="text"
            placeholder=""
            name="risk"
            className="form-control"
            value={risk}
          />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```